# extract SQL DESCRIBE TABLE output

Tags: sas, ddl

The following:

```
proc sql; describe table sashelp.class;
```

Produces (in the log):

```
create table SASHELP.CLASS( label='Student Data' bufsize=4096 )
  (
   Name char(8),
   Sex char(1),
   Age num,
   Height num,
   Weight num
  );
```

Any integrity constraints are sent to the output window - accessible in SAS via:

```
ods output IntegrityConstraints=MyDataset;
```

Short of redirecting the log (`proc printto`), or building a generator (via `proc contents` or dictionary / sashelp views) is there any other way to extract the aforementioned DDL?

I tried ODS TRACE but couldn't see any other outputs being created.

Comment: Actually, I'm having trouble parsing what you want from this.  You want the `create table...` bit, not the integrity constraints?  What do you really want - what are you going to use that information to do?

Comment: I want both actually..  My aim is to build a DDL generator.  I think the create table (log) output, combined with the constraints, gives me everything needed to recreate the dataset

Comment: Can't you just use `create table X like Y` to do that?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you might want that's not either `create table X like Y` or easier to get from `dictionary.columns/tables` than it would be from the above, so maybe I'm not seeing what you're doing.  You might consider `proc contents` for the same information, as it has a ton of ODS output objects you can grab.

Comment: The issue is that the base table is not accessible from the target environment (this is part of a promotion process).  Indeed all the info is accessible 'piecemeal' but was hoping for a slick approach..  In the meantime I'm just going with the log redirect strategy!

Comment: Ah, okay.  Yeah, I'm not aware of a way to specifically take the log above without log redirection.

Comment: I think you're right, happy to accept that if you put forward as an answer..

Comment: Your answer is fine as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Could be easier to just make a copy of your dataset with 0 obs, and move that to the target environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy redirecting your log (albeit temporarily) the following may be useful:

```
/* macro */
%macro get_ddl(ds=,outfile=);
   filename tmp temp;
   proc printto log=tmp;quit;
   proc sql; describe table &ds;
   proc printto log=log;quit;
   data _null_;
      infile tmp;
      file &outfile;
      input;
      if _infile_=:'NOTE: SQL table ' then start+1;
      else if _infile_=:'NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used' then stop;
      else if index(_infile_,'            The SAS System       ') then delete;
      else if start=1 then put _infile_;
      putlog _infile_;
   run;
   filename tmp;
%mend;

/* test */
proc sql;
create table people
   (
     name      char(14),
     gender    char(6),
     hired     num,
     jobtype   char(1) not null,
     status    char(10),

    constraint prim_key primary key(name),
    constraint gender check(gender in ('male' 'female')),
    constraint status check(status in ('permanent' 
                            'temporary' 'terminated')) 
  );

%get_ddl(ds=people,outfile="C:\temp\test.ddl");
```

Note that the column constraints are NOT on the above output (they need to be derived from the IntegrityConstraints output).

It does kinda feel strange that this info is not 'redirectable' though..